# using cublasSetMatrix in a pthread

Tags: cuda, pthreads

does cublasSetMatrix work if used in a separate pthread?

I want to overlap tasks on CPU with CPU->GPU data transfer. However, since the data is quite large, I'm trying to avoid allocate large pinned memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it won't. GPU contexts are tied to threads that created them. If you try running `cublasSetMatrix` or `cudaMemcpy` in another thread without doing anything else, it will make another context. Memory allocations are not portable between contexts, effectively every context has its own virtual address space. The result will be that you wind up with two GPU contexts, and the copy will fail.

The requirement for pinned memory comes from the CUDA driver. For overlapping copying and execution, the host memory involved in the copying must be in a physical address range that the GPU can access by DMA over the PCI-e bus. That is why pinning is required, otherwise the host memory could be in swap space or other virtual memory, and the DMA transaction would fail.

If you are worried about the amount of pinned host memory required for large problems, try using one or two smaller pinned buffers and executing multiple transfers, using the pinned memory as staging buffers. The performance won't be quite as good as using a single large pinned buffer and one big transfer, but you can still achieve useful kernel/copy overlap and hide a lot of PCI-e latency in the process.

Comment: thanks a lot of the detail explanation. So, what happen if cudaMemcpy2DAsync is used with non-pinned memory. I notice that it does work with the correct transfer, but what about the overlapping? Is that still asynchronous?

Comment: No it isn't. If the host memory isn't pinned and the copy isn't launched into a stream, the behaviour is the same as the block cudaMemcpy2D call. If my response answered your question, perhaps you could be so kind as to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). That way it is marked as answered.